# Disable header click on jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, wizard

How can I disable the header click for jQuery tabs.

I only want to change the tabs from elements inside the tab, building a component that work as a Wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(tab).click(function(){ 
return false;
});
```

will prevent the default action of that tab